# How search with vimeo api?

Tags: c#, api, search, video, vimeo

I register my application at vimeo.com . I want search videos with vimeo advanced api. I try many times but my request url was wrong. How write correct request in c# or javascript to get response with searched videos.

Comment: please show the code of the most likely to work try you did so we use it as starting point :)

Comment: @Davide Piras  I tried different, ways but most likely I get error: "The oauth_nonce passed has already been used". I am not good understanding how to create correct request url. Please, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aram, I used this C# library by Rob Green. You can tailor it to your needs, but it includes search routine:

[C# Wrapper for Vimeo Advanced API](http://www.robgreen.me/post/Getting-Started-With-The-Vimeo-API-in-C.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Rob Green's library links are 404ing. It would be great if someone explained how to sign the url and return the signed request to the client so that jsonp from jquery could be used.

Comment: I have just seen that you experienced trouble accessing my website, apologies for this. It is working now!